# Evaluate the type switch and perform the action

Tags: oracle-apex

I have several fields in a dialog, including a switch field.
Here the user chooses between [Yes] and [No].

If the user has now selected [No] and then clicks the [Update] button, all data records with the corresponding ID should be deleted in a table.

I have two processes for this.

1. Delete - process
2. Update - process

Delete - process

```
    declare
        l_script varchar2(32000);
    begin
       if :P161000_ENTI_ID = 0 then
          l_script := 'DELETE 
                            FROM 
                                TBL_MGM_MI_TO_ENTI 
                            WHERE 
                                MIL_PKEY =  :P161000_PKEY
                                ';
           
        end if;
        return;

end;
```

But it doesn't work. I would like if the user chooses [No], the data records are deleted in the table.The update process saves the other values ​​from the dialog in another table. That's working.

How can I now query on the [Yes] [No]?
How can I evaluate the switch field, depending on what was selected?

Comment: I noticed you don't mark any of your questions as answered. Can you pls do that - it is the best way to show your appreciation for the persons investing their time in helping you.

Answer (score 1):

The delete process above does not do a delete. It declares a variable that has a delete statement in it and that is it. The delete is not done. Also, you don't need the return statement.
To make it work you need to execute the statement using "EXECUTE IMMEDIATE"

```
DECLARE
  l_script VARCHAR2(32000);
BEGIN
  IF :P161000_ENTI_ID = 0 THEN
    l_script := 'DELETE FROM TBL_MGM_MI_TO_ENTI WHERE MIL_PKEY =  :PKEY ';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_script USING :P161000_PKEY;
  END IF;
END;
```

In this case however, you can do it a lot easier by just executing the dml in your block without using EXECUTE IMMEDIATE.

```
BEGIN
  IF :P161000_ENTI_ID = 0 THEN
    DELETE FROM  TBL_MGM_MI_TO_ENTI WHERE  MIL_PKEY =  :P161000_PKEY;
  END IF;
END;
```

or... you could put a server side condition on the delete process of type ITEM is Value. Set item to P161000_ENTI_ID and value to 0 and then just need the delete statement.

```
DELETE FROM  TBL_MGM_MI_TO_ENTI WHERE  MIL_PKEY =  :P161000_PKEY;
```